# Express Routing HTML5 Style CatchAll Conundrum no HASHBangs - Angular JS, Yeoman

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, gruntjs, yeoman

Hi I'm at the very beginning stages of a new project.

I am going to be using yeomans modern workflow tools for the front end, angular js work.

Backend written in node.js using express. I do not want to create any html on the server, it is all to be served to the client statically and then accessible via a RESTful service written in express where the magic of the angular js application will create the dynamic content. The app is to be one-page. As its one page there will need to be a catchall rule for views.

Currently I have the typical structure of:

```
app.js
public < dir containing the static html, js, css etc.
 index.html
 scripts
 styles
 views
```

I have found that most people render html server side and then have angular or whatever framework to provide further content. People typically use jade templating on the server to serve content, I do not see the need for this as all content is going to be very dynamic.

Yeoman's workflow is so simple and powerful I do not want to disturb this. For many reasons when you add a new route yeoman adds the js reference to the bottom of the index.html, due to templating being a different syntax I cannot use yeoman for this.

I also like the seperation of concerns in this architecture as well. The express installation primarily focuses on the RESTful service and has no control over the presentation and then the /public folder serves the presentation which is provided by using express.static(PATH).

I can happily use hashbangs for routing but its not so trivial for html5 pushstate.

My issue is with the routing on catch all. The trouble I'm finding is to effectively redirect all traffic that is not under the /api resource url. Whilst not interrupting assets being replaced with the index.html.

```
app.get(url('/person/lesson/:id'), api.getLesson);

app.all('*', routes.index);
```

I have tried:

```
routes.index = function(req,res){
res.sendfile('./public/dist/index.html');
};

routes.index = function(req,res){
res.redirect('/');
};
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Put your API routes (get, post, delete, etc.) before the catch. There's no need to redirect.

```
app.get('*', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('public/index.html');
});
```

There's nothing else to it.

Comment: Hi I have tried this, it works in principle for the index.html but doesn't work for other files in the public folder.

Comment: You need to check if the file they're asking for exists in the public folder.

     `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client/public'));`

Answer (score 2):

By putting static routes and other predefined routes ahead of your catchall code below, this will work.

```
app.get('*', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
```

Note however that if you are using static routes, say for a /public/ folder mapped to /, those routes need to be referenced in your HTML using **absolute** references (i.e. "/css/styles.css" not "css/styles.css").  If you use relative URLs (without the /), then the reference will be based off of the URI and fall into the catchall because of that relative URL not being defined.